# How to execute form submit for each file in file input?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have set up HTML5/PHP file upload and open, only to realize that there is the nice `multiple` attribute that makes it possible to upload several files.

Is it possible to just run the submit of a `form` *once for each* file separately? So,

1. submit for file[1],
2. submit for file[2],

etc.

Or will I have to make that happen server side?

This is my submit *all at once* code:

```
<form id="import-dialog-form" target="_blank" action="open.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Edit**

There is some instructions on how to submit forms via ajax.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Unfortunately, it does not open the file in a new tab as my form does.

Comment: On server side is the great idea, I think !

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in client side. You need to work in DOM. So once 3 files has been upload and you don't want to to work in Server side, you could still work with them in client side from the Temp data.

Comment: Do you mean I can access it somehow with javascript or so? How can I work with the data on the client side?